# User Control inside App Code Folder throws Errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, app-code

I'm currently trying to debug an existing project. After fixing some dll reference all seems to run well except we got an error:

> The File '/App_Code/UserControl.ascx' is in the special directory 'App Code', which is not allowed.

The error is pointing at this line:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="UC" Src="../App_Code/UserControl.ascx" %>
```

I did some research and found out that your not suppose to put controls in App Code folder but this somehow work for them so far.

Changing the location of the file generates more errors.

Can anyone please suggest options in fixing this?

Comment: I think that you only can place a `UserControl` in the `App_Code` folder [if it only contains inline code](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/10/01/asp-net-2-0-user-controls-in-app_code.aspx). If you have a codebehind file it is not allowed. Everything that is in that folder will be compiled at runtime. But i'm not so familiar with website projects.

Comment: You'll probably just have to dig through all the errors caused by moving it, manually fixing up references. Maintenance programming is a dirty job, but somebody's got to do it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It turns out that this was coded in VS 2005 and it was still allowed back then to add user controls with code behind in App Code folder...hmm is changing the location of the user control the best move here? or would it be better if i just install 2005 to support this project?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Nathan your answer helped me into figuring this out. Just renamed the folder to keep the classes correct. want to add your answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably just have to dig through all the errors caused by moving it, manually fixing up references. Maintenance programming is a dirty job, but somebody's got to do it. That, or (as turned out to be useful) rename the folder to something else and fix any remaining errors.